# How to insert csv file data into database?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Currently I am doing a project in php for uploading CSV file and to insert data into database.After CSV file uploaded it displays the data present in file with checkboxes.On Clicking the checkbox the values are not getting inserted into the table.

The Coding I used

```
  if(isset($_POST['upload']))
  {
  if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']))
  {
      echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['filename']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h1>";
  }

  $handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");
  echo("<table border='1'>");
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
  {
    echo("<tr>\r\n");
    foreach ($data as $index=>$val)
    {
        echo("\t<td><input type='checkbox' name='chk1[]' value='$val'>$val</td>\r\n");
    }

  }
  echo("</tr>\r\n");
  echo("</table>");
  echo("<input type='submit' name='insert' id='insert' value='Submit' />");
  fclose($handle);
  }
```

On Uploading the file the values get displayed,but clicking on submit button no action is performed.

The Code for Submit button is:

```
if(isset($_POST['insert']))
{
for($i=0;$i < sizeof($checkbox1);$i++)
{
$query = "INSERT INTO uploadmail (name,email) VALUES ('$name','".$checkbox1[$i]."')";
$result = mysql_query($query);
}
}
```

The values displayed like this
    [image]

Please give your suggestions.THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Comment: Take a look at the `LOAD DATA` SQL query.

Comment: I dont think you should redirect inside of a loop, never seen that before

Comment: I changed that but then also it is not working @Fred -ii-

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.  Also `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can download reader.php and oleread.inc zip folder from this site http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/

and rest of code to insert data in database

require_once 'Excel/reader.php';

```
// ExcelFile($filename, $encoding);

$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();

// Set output Encoding.

$data->setOutputEncoding('CP1251');



$data->read($_FILES['excel_upload']['tmp_name']);



error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);



for ($i=1;$i<=$data->sheets[0]['numRows'];$i++) 

{   
          $EmailAdd   = $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][1];

          $NameAdd    = $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][2];

          $Phone      = $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][3];

          $Address    = mysql_real_escape_string($data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][4]);


             if(filter_var($EmailAdd, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))

                  {

                    $currentId = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Student` (`StudentEmail_email`,StudentEmail_Name`,`StudentEmail_Mobile`,`StudentEmail_Address`) VALUES ('$EmailAdd','$NameAdd','$ContactAdd','$Address')");

                  }


}
```

Comment: You can download reader.php and oleread.inc zip folder from this site http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/

Answer (score 0):

### Remarks:

- I have included some explanations in the code quoted in `/* */`.
- I changed your insert query to *MySQLi Prepared Statement* rather than the
  *deprecated MySQL*.

Here's a code that you can use.

```
if(isset($_POST['upload']))
  {
  if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']))
  {
      echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['filename']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h1>";
  }

  $handle = file_get_contents($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']); /* GET THE CONTENT OF UPLOADED FILE */

  $val = explode(',',$handle);
  $count = count($val); /* COUNT THE TOTAL EXPLODED RESULT */

  echo("<table border='1'>");

    for($x=0;$x<=$count;$x++){ /* START THE LOOP BASED FROM THE COUNTED RESULT */

    echo("<tr>\r\n");

        echo("\t<td><input type='checkbox' name='chk1[$x]' value='$val[$x]'>$val[$x]</td>\r\n"); /* GET THE VALUE AND STORE IT INTO THE chk1 ARRAY */

    echo("</tr>\r\n");

    } /* END OF FOR LOOP */

  echo("</table>");
  echo("<input type='submit' name='insert' id='insert' value='Submit' />");

} /* END OF ISSET UPLOAD */
```

I just noticed that you don't have the `move_uploaded_file`. Or you just didn't include it in your sample code?

And after selecting/checking the check boxes and submitting the form:

```
if(isset($_POST['insert']))
{
  $comp=count($_POST['chk1']); /* COUNT THE TOTAL SUBMITTED CHECKBOX */
  $checkbox1=$_POST['chk1'];

  for($i=0;$i<=$comp;$i++)
  {
    if(!empty($checkbox1[$i])){ /* IF SUBMITTED DATA IS CHECKED */
      /* WHERE DOES YOUR $name VARIABLE CAME FROM? */
      $stmt = $YourSQLConnection->prepare("INSERT INTO uploadmail (name,email) VALUES (?, ?)");
      $stmt->bind_param('ss', $name,$checkbox1[$i]); /* BIND THE VALUE TO STRINGS */
    }
  }
}
```